# CSS bottom transition not smooth

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, css-transitions

```js
$(function(){
 
 function boxtoRight(){
  $("#box").animate({marginLeft: 600},3000,'linear',boxtoLeft);
 }
 function boxtoLeft(){
  $("#box").animate({marginLeft: 0},3000,'linear',boxtoRight);
 }
 boxtoRight();


 $(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 32){
   $("#box").css("background","green");
   $("#box").css("bottom","200px").css("transition","0.2s");
  }
 });
 $(document).keyup(function(e){ 
  if(e.keyCode == 32){
   $("#box").css("background","red");
   $("#box").css("bottom","130px").css("transition","0.2s");
  }
 });

});
```

```css
#container{
 background: #ccc;
 width: 600px;
 height: 200px;
}
#box{
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
 background: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is I am trying to make the box jump when I press the spacebar. Right now if I press spacebar, the box jumps but the animation is not smooth.

Also, how to move the box to the center of window with animate,scrolling and go to Right of document?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "move box to the center of windowscreen with animate,scrolling and go to Right of document". If you explain more clearly what you want, I can update my answer.

Comment: box is always position center of screen when start from left to right
same like  mario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here. In the CSS transition property, you need to specify which property the transition applies to. So I've updated your CSS to include `transition: bottom 0.2`. I also gave `#container` `position: relative` so the `bottom` property of `#box` is relative to the bottom of `#container`.

```
#container{
    background: #ccc;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative; //added
}    

#box{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;  //added
    transition: bottom 0.2s; //added
}
```

Now in your Javascript, you no longer need to change the `transition` property. Also, instead of calling `.css()` multiple times, I've updated to changed multiple properties on a single `.css()` call. Finally, I've changed the values of `bottom`, since it is now relative to the bottom of `#container`.

```
$(function(){

    function boxtoRight(){
        $("#box").animate({marginLeft: 510 },3000,'linear',boxtoLeft);
    }
    function boxtoLeft(){
        $("#box").animate({marginLeft: 0},3000,'linear',boxtoRight);
    }
    boxtoRight();


    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            $("#box").css({"background":"green",
                           "bottom":"70px"
            });
        }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e){ 
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            $("#box").css({"background":"red",
                           "bottom":"0px"
            });
         }
     });
});
```

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s3pfrhn8/2/

Comment: Thanks, it's work and is it possible when the box jump 1 sec(hold the spacebar) can let the box down?